# Cannot Select an Item twice in CollectionView and when tried with work around, fires event twice in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am using MVVM pattern. I am having a `CollectionView` whose items when selected calls a Command in **ViewModel**.

The First problem is that I cannot select an Item twice. I can have some workaround and make it work like setting `CollectionView.SelectedItem = null`.

The Second problem is that, when I set `CollectionView.SelectedItem = null`, `SelectionChangedCommand` is called twice (firstly for Selecting an Item, secondly due to setting `SelectedItem = null`). That is `Company Selected Name = " + SelectedCompany.Name` is printed twice in the ViewModel.

**Here's my XAML Code:**

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding CompanyListItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCompany}"
                             SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding CompanySelectedCommand}"
                             SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged">
                             SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**C# Code Behind:**

```cs
void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as CollectionView).SelectedItem != null)
        (sender as CollectionView).SelectedItem = null;
}
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public class CompaniesListPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CompaniesListPageViewModel()
    {
        CompanySelectedCommand = new Command<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(execute: (SelectionChangedEventArgs args) => CompanySelected(args));
    }

    public CompanyListItem SelectedCompany
    {
        get { return selectedCompany; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                selectedCompany = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCompany));
            }
        }
    }

    CompanyListItem selectedCompany;

    void CompanySelected(SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Company Selected Name = " + SelectedCompany.Name); 
        Navigation.PushAsync(new CompanyDetailPage(SelectedCompany));
    }
}
```

Comment: An alternative is to add a GestureRecognizer to your StackLayout, it will only fire when the item is tapped. For this you will have to remove most of your selectionChanged events

Comment: SelectionChanged is fired before chaning the value of the collectionView.SelectedItem. instead of checking the sender, you can compare the SelectionChangedEventArgs, you can access to `e.CurrentSelection` and to `e.PreviousSelection`

Comment: `SelectionChanged` fires when the selection **changes**.  If you choose the same option twice, it is not changing and the event does not fire.  That is by design.  It is unclear what problem this is actually causing you that you need to fix?

Comment: @Jason, The application goes to next page based on the item selected. When I go to the back page again and select the same item, it does not work. How to make it work?

Comment: that is why you should set the SelectedItem to null before you navigate.  Why are you using both the event and command and event for SelectionChanged?  You should use one or the other, not both

Comment: @Jason, that was because, when coming back from next page to Home page, we cannot select the item again that was selected previously.

Comment: again, setting the SelectedItem to null is the workaround for this.  There is no reason you need to use both the command and the event in order to do this

Comment: @Jason, you mean setting `SelectedItem = null` in the code behind, I've tried that, it is firing the `SelectionChanged` twice. On the other hand, when setting `SelectedCompany = null` after `Navigation.PushAsync(...)` in **ViewModel**, it is not working while going back to Home page and selecting the previous item again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used `SelectionChanged` in Code Behind, so you don't need `SelectionChangedCommand` in your xaml.

please refer to the following code,I tested on sample code [VerticalListSingleSelectionPage.xaml.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/UserInterface/CollectionViewDemos/CollectionViewDemos/Views/Selection/VerticalListSingleSelectionPage.xaml.cs), and it works properly on my side.

```
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"                      
                    SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged">
```

And code behind:

```
    void   OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var MyCollectionView = sender as CollectionView;
        if (MyCollectionView.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

         UpdateSelectionData(e.PreviousSelection, e.CurrentSelection);

        //clear selection 
        MyCollectionView.SelectedItem = null;
    }

    void UpdateSelectionData(IEnumerable<object> previousSelectedItems, IEnumerable<object> currentSelectedItems)
    {
        string previous = (previousSelectedItems.FirstOrDefault() as Monkey)?.Name;
        string current = (currentSelectedItems.FirstOrDefault() as Monkey)?.Name;

        Monkey currentMonkey  = (currentSelectedItems.FirstOrDefault() as Monkey);

        if (currentMonkey!=null) { 
           Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(currentMonkey));
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

> I want to do it using MVVM. Hence I want to navigate to another page
> from my ViewModel class.

For this, you can do refer the following code:

```
async void  MonkeySelectionChangedAsync()
{
    if (SelectedMonkey!=null) {
        SelectedMonkeyMessage = $"Selection {selectionCount}: {SelectedMonkey.Name}";
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMonkeyMessage");
        selectionCount++;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-----------> " + SelectedMonkey.Name);

        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(SelectedMonkey));
    }
}
```

And you need init `selectedMonkey`  to `null`at first at the constructor of your viewmodel.

```
    public MonkeysViewModel()
    {
        selectedMonkey = null;

        //  other code

     }
```

After that, assign `SelectedItem` to `null` in function `OnAppearing`:

```
       protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        //mCollectionView is the `x:Name` of your `CollectionView`
        mCollectionView.SelectedItem = null;   
    }
```

And the xaml is:

```
    <CollectionView 
                    x:Name="mCollectionView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"           
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonkey}"
                    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding MonkeySelectionChangedCommand}"
                   >
```

**Note:** You can modify your code based on the above code.

Comment: I want to do it using **MVVM**. Hence I want to navigate to another page from my ViewModel class.

Comment: I have updated my reply, you can check it at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: It works for the part *"I can select the same item multiple times"*, but the problem is, when I come back to the HomePage from the DetailPage, `SelectionChangedCommand` is again fired due to `mCollectionView.SelectedItem = null` in `OnAppearing()`. Hence it again takes me to the detail page without clicking anything.